# upgraded rails 3 app rake db:reset error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I upgraded my rails 2.3.8 app to rails 3. when I run the rake db:reset command, it returns the following error

*rake aborted!
test-unit is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.
/Users/Shenario/Desktop/stack24/Rakefile:7:in `'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)*

i'm new to rails, and wud be glad if you guys out ther coud help me! thanks!

the trace --

rake aborted!
test-unit is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.
/Users/Shenario/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:102:in `block in cripple_rubygems'
/Users/Shenario/Desktop/stack24/lib/tasks/rspec.rake:1:in`'
/Users/Shenario/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:131:in `load'
/Users/Shenario/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:131:in`block in load_tasks'
/Users/Shenario/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:131:in `each'
/Users/Shenario/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:131:in`load_tasks'
/Users/Shenario/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:141:in `load_tasks'
/Users/Shenario/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in`method_missing'
/Users/Shenario/Desktop/stack24/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Shenario/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in`load'
/Users/Shenario/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/Shenario/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017:in`block in load_rakefile'
/Users/Shenario/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Shenario/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in`load_rakefile'
/Users/Shenario/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000:in `block in run'
/Users/Shenario/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in`standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Shenario/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Users/Shenario/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31:in`'
/Users/Shenario/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/Shenario/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/rake:19:in`'

Comment: Have you installed test-unit gem? Try running your command with --trace option and post the trace for better understanding.

Comment: Hi Harry, thanks for the response, ve added my trace, if possible, plz clarify. thanks

Comment: I'm having the same error, any solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

After searching for "test-unit", found this:

```
gem 'test-unit', '2.0.7' if RUBY_VERSION.to_f >= 1.9
```

in lib/tasks/rspec.rake

I suspected it was caused by me copying the whole lib folder from older rails version to this new one.

Solution: removed that file, then things seem to work fine after.

Basically I suggest you look at lib/tasks and see if there are rake tasks that are incompatible with rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

you must have at least

```
gem "rails", "~> 3.0.3"
```

in your Gemfile, then remove Gemfile.lock (if any) and run:

```
bundle check
```

if you need some missing gems, run:

```
bundle install
```

bundler will install all required gems at least for rails 3.0.3, including test-unit gem. btw remember that a migration from rails 2.3.x to 3.0.x in most cases requires some code changes.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Gemfile (replacing VERSION with your required version number).

```
gem 'test-unit', 'VERSION', :platform => :ruby_19
```

For Rails 2.3.11, I needed version 1.2.3 of the test-unit gem.